# Missing file name suggestions using views module

Tags: drupal-views, drupal-8

I have been working on a Drupal 8 theme using views module. For some reason, the module fails to display the list of file name suggestions.

At first I believed that the problem was sole in displaying the suggestions. However, after creating a new template file, following the pattern (**views-view-unformatted--news-article-listings.html.twig**), and rebuilding the cache, the file is ignored.

The picture bellow is the output of the twig file with debugging turned on.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old issue, but readers may be interested in this issue
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2923634#comment-12417950

Core Views does not currently supply theme suggestions in Drupal 8

The fix is being worked on, but the patch in #8 worked for me (v 8.5.5), and I can now see views theme suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I think that theme suggestions from views module are buggy. Now Im doing project, where there is none of them:

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'block' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * block--mdb-content.html.twig
   * block--system-main-block.html.twig
   * block--system.html.twig
   x block.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/mdb/templates/block/block.html.twig' -->
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'container' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/form/container.html.twig' -->
<div class="views-element-container">
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'views_view' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/views/views-view.html.twig' -->
<div class="wrapper js-view-dom-id-8f70d5c8af23f92729c2180de609f1a2df672d7711b56b0a606853692ee787cd">
```

You can see, that file name suggestions works well on top, but under views_view hook i dont see any. But we can remember how they should look from Drupal 8 documentation:

**View, named foobar. Style: unformatted. Row style: Fields. Display: Page.**

```
views-view--foobar--page.html.twig
views-view--page.html.twig
views-view--foobar.html.twig
views-view.html.twig

views-view-unformatted--foobar--page.html.twig
views-view-unformatted--page.html.twig
views-view-unformatted--foobar.html.twig
views-view-unformatted.html.twig

views-view-fields--foobar--page.html.twig
views-view-fields--page.html.twig
views-view-fields--foobar.html.twig
views-view-fields.html.twig
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.theme.inc/group/views_templates/8.2.x